How to set CQL_FILTER and recalculate layer boundary values through interface calls
Scenario description:

GIS data volume is tens of millions and requires the creation of multi-dimensional layers, using WTMS's tile cache for rendering
Using the CQL_FILTER condition to filter data and render layers with specific conditions
There are a large number of layers, and the creation and configuration of layers are batch processed using Java API calls

Problems that occurred:
The boundary values of the layer are calculated by default based on the data source, without narrowing down the range according to the set CQL_FILTER condition, resulting in a large number of useless blank images occupying a lot of storage space in the cache slice and thus increasing the cache time
Expected solution:
After setting CQL_FILTER, the layer boundary values can be recalculated. This function can be achieved by manually operating the geoserer management interface, but no solution was found through the API interface


I suspect you will need to implement a recalculate option for the layer endpoint similar to the one found in the coverages and mosaics.

public void configureCQLFilter(String workspaceName, String storename, String layerName, String cqlFilter) throws IOException {
//Modify the cqlFilter filtering conditions of the layer, recalculate the layer boundaries, and reset the layer boundary values
String geoserverURL = this.url + "/rest/workspaces/"+workspaceName+"/datastores/"+storename+"/featuretypes/"

layerName + ".xml?recalculate=nativebbox,latlonbbox";
String xmlPayload = ""+cqlFilter+"";
sendRequest(geoserverURL, "PUT", xmlPayload);}


Thank you for inspiring me. I searched for recalculate in the source code and found the key interface and parameter settings
